# Getting One to Many onto one line

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables

**Sales Order**:

- SONumber
- SOCompanyCode
- SOItemNumber
- SOWorkFlowLastCode
- SOWorkFlowNextCode
- SOLotNumber
- SOItemDescription
- SORequestNumber
- SORequestQuantity
- SODateUpdated

and

**Purchase Order**:

- PONumber
- POItemNumber
- POCompanyCode
- POQuantity
- PODeliveryDate
- POWorkFlowNextCode

I am attempting to write a query that looks for all Sales Orders with SOWorkFlowLastCode = 980 and SOWorkFlowNextCode = 999 and SODateUpdated is today.

Then looks for all of the Purchase Orders that POItemNumber = SOItemNumber and POCompanyCode = SOCompanyCode and POWorkFlowNextCode != 999

All above is easy for me.

The hard part is that there can be 0 to multiple purchase orders for the same Item number and I need all of those purchase orders onto the same line.

Comment: This kind of **rollup** is possible, but it's normally considered the responsibility of the client app.

Comment: I am setting this up to run once a day at the end of the day and to email myself and another individual the results. I need to get the desired results first though but this is why it will be on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, dbo.GetSalesOrders(id) as sales_orders

CREATE FUNCTION GetSalesOrders(@id int)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @result VARCHAR(max)
   SET @result = ''
   SELECT @result = @result + orderNumber + ', ' FROM salesItems WHERE someID = @id
   IF (@result <> '') SET @result = LEFT(@result, LEN(@result) -1)
   RETURN @result
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using two temp tables. 
One for the desired Sales Orders that meet the critera with an additional column called PODetails. 
Then had another temp table that pulled all the Purchase Orders that meet the critea.

From there I did an update to the Sales Order temp table setting the PODetails equal to a STUFF from the Purchase Order temp table getting the Purchase Order Number, Quantity, and date and casting them to VARCHAR where temp table Item Numbers match FOR XML PATH('')

Then I can just select * From the Sales Order temp table for my full results.

Thanks